# Avengers: why doesn't Ultron make backups?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

One of the plot points of *Age of Ultron* is that Ultron is not a robot, it is an intelligence hosted into many separate robots. As a consequence, the only way to destroy it is to destroy each individual robot; so long as even one robot remains, Ultron is still there and can go on Ultroning. And yet, Ultron decides to bring *every single robot* hosting his intelligence into the final battle. The Avengers destroy all the robots and Ultron is no more (technically, this is a spoiler, but seriously, did anybody think even for a moment that anything different was ever going to happen?)

But things didn't have to be this way. Ultron could have done what effectively amounts to a security backup: take a couple dozen robots and hide them in various remote secure locations. Given the size of his army, this wouldn't have affected the immediate outcome of the final battle (if the Avengers can take on an Army of 1000 robots, they can also take on an Army of 1020 robots), but Ultron could have used the backup to remain active and stage a comeback some time in the future.

Comment: How do you know it didn't?

Comment: You are right. This was the only one thing they did right in the otherwise unspeakable terminator 3. An AI has no central computer that could be destroyed. Beside if its architecture prohibits distribution (An evil AI does not want to have full functional (and eventually rivaling) copies of itself I think) but even then it could easily make backups.

Comment: To be frank, if the Avengers: Age of Ultron was stupidest movie ever made. There was no intellectual background. Just fights and fights.

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri: “Avengers: Age of Ultron was stupidest movie ever made” — there’s quite a lot of competition for that. And do you expect intellectual background in a summer blockbuster?

Comment: The comic book Ultron was defeated repeatedly, but has come back with a new body equally repeatedly. While "comic book regular villain becomes one-off film villain" is not a surprise, having a backup survive for a future movie is something that people might well have thought for a moment might happen. And as @jonrsharpe suggests, no one will be surprised if a future movie decides that's what happened after all.

Comment: You know, there are billions of people out there that use digital files and despite repeated warning the vast majority still don't do backups :P.

Comment: "Did anyone thing anything different was ever going to happen?" - I'd like to introduce you to a little world called Mirrodin. Or as it's now know, New Phyrexia.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg has it right - no-one thinks to keep off-site backups until after your first catastrophe. Most of just manage to survive that one. :)

Comment: Didn't they say that Jarvis/Vision was preventing Ultron from using the internet to escape?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg is spot-on: plenty of people don't backup, and many of them aren't nearly as arrogant and convinced of their own invincibility as Ultron.

Comment: When his internet connection was cut off Ultron was only able to transfer/copy himself via bluetooth with limited range, hence he had more backups but no way to reach them

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe it's never made explicit in the movies whether Ultron is a distributed neural network with all robots networked together to form a single "brain" or if he exists as a single consciousness controlling his robots remotely with the ability to move from host to host.

The fact that he escapes to the net but is later successfully isolated from it into physical bodies suggests that it's the latter. Ultron is either unwilling or unable to distribute his consciousness across multiple systems.

I would argue that Ultron is unwilling because of the implications of the [Duplicates Paradox](http://www.benbest.com/philo/doubles.html). If he created distinct copies of himself, each would likely consider only itself to be real or original. Given that Ultron's reasoning was created from a human template, it's more likely that any copies would compete with each other rather than work together. The existential dread and potential identity crisis that copying would have on the emotionally immature brain that calls itself Ultron, coupled with the conviction of his own superiority outweighed the security that backups would offer.

Comment: Thats a very good point. Two Ultrons would probably end up competing which would be very detrimental to exterminating humanity.

Comment: Which raises the question, why didn't Tony Stark et. al. create a second copy? :D

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark I think because Ultron was finished when Stark was at the party. Upon his "birth" he attacked JARVIS and escaped without leaving a copy behind.

Comment: Its **very** clear that Ultron is not a Hive Mind.

Comment: @cde: Because he has no strings? :-)

Comment: @cde It certainly seems that way but as I recall the movie doesn't really dwell on the science of what Ultron *is*. But whether it's part of his character design or just a consequence of the movie's direction Ultron ends up as little more than your classic Evil Villain. I'd say that he's not even a true post-singularity AI but rather a very advanced simulation. It's interesting to consider whether he's really aware of his own existence or just pretending to be.

Comment: Because a Hive Mind is typically defined like the Borg, a collective of individuals that form a single er, collective. Or the Geth, multiple Geth programs in a single platform. Ultron is a single mind that can manipulate multiple pieces of hardware, like Skynet.

Comment: @cde You're right, perhaps I shouldn't have suggested a hive mind. I guess I was comparing him more to classic dystopian AIs that spread a single consciousness across hundreds of thousands of nodes, increasing in intelligence with each host. Ultron quite clearly isn't one of those, strengthening my belief that he's just an advanced simulation not true AI.

Comment: Pretty sure JARVIS, who had been shutting Ultron down where nukes were concerned, would have pounced on any net-based Ultron backups.

Answer (score 8):

Ultron was vain when it comes to certain aspects. He was completely confident that he would win over the Avengers with his army. Also, towards the middle of the battle, he realised that Avengers were overpowering him, and hence needed to use the full force of his numbers.

He could've escaped through the internet, but this was the first thing that Vision cut off. He cut off Ultron's internet access(I believe that's the cruelest thing anybody did to Ultron :P Oh the horror!).

His factory was also destroyed(presumably) when Sokovia took off.

So in the end, he has no way to create more copies.

And he did escape to one of his inferior robot shells later, but Vision takes care of that.

Comment: ... *or did he?*

Comment: :O Well maybe... who knows... WHO knows..... :P

Comment: The shadow knows. Or the Watcher. I always get those two mixed up

Comment: @cde Or the watcher's shadow...